# TFS: How to reset all permissions?

Tags: permissions, team-foundation-server

The question is simple, how to reset all permissions to defaults on Team Foundation Server 2013? The second part: how to make sure I won't be locked out of TFS when doing the reset?

The best option would be to reset all the permissions for the whole TFS server, but I'll accept resetting the permissions on individual team project collections as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. The permissions in TFS are created at the time the team project is created and there is no way to get back to the original set automatically.

You can create a new Team Project and painstakingly go through all of the permissions and manually set them.